# Should I aim for 100% test coverage on Jacoco?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, code-coverage

I am currently working on increasing the test coverage of a project, it is around 93% and I am working my way towards 100%.

I noticed that one of the blocks that are not being covered is the **main method** and it looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Even though the application has over 90 tests, and some with the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, this **main method** is still not covered.

Should I worry about this and make sure I get a 100% coverage? Or am I being too much of a perfectionist and **certain things are just not worth to test**, like the example above?

Why is the code above not being ran through the tests? Do I need to explicitly call the main method for it to be ran? I was expecting it to be called when the application starts up.

Comment: what would you test for this method? that the args parser works in spring? That it finds the Application class?

Comment: The way I see it, it would be more of a regression test. In the case that someone add some code to that method that makes it misbehave. Does that make sense? If not, should I just leave this method untested and tell jacoco to ignore it somehow?

Comment: You should not, the effort spent doesn't cover the actual benefit from this. Usually you'll want to test places like this with higher-level testing that would treat your application as an executable file rather than code. besides, coverage itself doesn't prove anything - just that the code was executed during testing, it doesn't tell if it is correct, it's just a by-side metric.

Comment: @Etki Testing never proves [perfection](http://www.geraldmweinberg.com/Site/Perfect_Software.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should I aim for 100 %? Yes, always!. However having said that anything above 90% is considered good. It may not be possible to achieve a 100% in all scenarios.

Talking about "main method", since it is just used for the startup of a spring boot application and does not cover any functionality you can simply exclude the class which contains the main method from coverage in your pom.xml file using the following lines of code inside properties tag:

```
 <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
  **/com/example/test/MainApplication.java
</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Code coverage** by itself **is a useless metrics**. It doesn't tell you how your code/requirements are covered. It can only point to the places that are not covered completely. It's very easy to reach 100% with horrible tests that don't actually check anything.

Moreover - if people are exposed to the metrics, they do whatever they can to improve them. Instead of doing what's useful. So (at least on my practice) after introducing these metrics people start writing worse tests with worse coverage (I'm not talking about line coverage here).

If you really care about the quality of testing you should do code reviews. If you like metrics and want to stick with the line/branch coverage at least also introduce mutation testing.

So in the end: no, you shouldn't try to reach 100% of line or branch coverage.

Answer (score 3):

You don't do unit testing for the fun of it. Therefore you also look at coverage for a distinct purpose.

The purpose is: building software that has the required quality. You don't measure things and set goals because you can, but because the process of doing so helps improving the quality of your product.

Thus: when you can clearly define the additional value of testing such code, then it is worth investing time here. Especially because investing time for this costs energy that you can't use for other things.

Long story short: sit down with the people in your team and assess the return of investment that such tests (and beyond that goals like 100 percent coverage) and then follow the outcome of that. In other words: don't look (too much) for advice from strangers to determine your own priorities. You know your product, we don't.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I aim to 100% test coverage[...]?

yes.

But you should *not* cover lines of code, but **requirements**.

Your automated tests (*unit test*, *module tests* and *acceptance tests*) should cover 100% of the requirements fixed in the project documentation.

The best way to achieve that is *test driven development*.

TDD will not lead to 100% coverage, but it creates a trustworthy safety net which is much more valuable as a certain amount of measurable test coverage.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that we should aim for 100% coverage. There is a [valid argument](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15#issuecomment-337836586) that the `main` method is not a generated code and potentially you could write some extra logic in the method. So you should write a test covering it.

For your particular example of the `main` method to bootstrap a Spring Boot application I can propose the following concise JUnit 5 test

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ApplicationTest {

  @Test
  void main() {
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> Application.main(new String[]{}));
  }

}
```